# Can I see my Apps Scripts in one place

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, drive

Can I create a desktop icon or browser bookmark which will take me into a view of all my scripts? (All three of them!)

About once a quarter my apps lose their permission to handle Gmail. This causes me instant stress, inhibiting my ability to find, and edit the script.

Eventually, I find my way into Google Drive, find the script, and edit it. Running it brings up the lack of authority, which is then easily fixed. All three scripts need the same fix.

So, I'd like some sort of shortcut which would take me directly to a view of all my scripts.

Comment: You can only search standalone scripts not ones bound to another entity

Answer (score 1):

You can save a drive search from the url:

[search?q=type:application/vnd.google-apps.script](https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=type:application/vnd.google-apps.script)

This will list all independent scripts on your drive. As mentioned before bounded scripts will not be show and for the moment I think it's impossible

Comment: That works for me, I see my three scripts. I don't have a clue what makes a script bounded.

Comment: Here's one of my scripts:
function cleanUp1month() {
  var delayDays = 31 // Delete anything older than 31 days
  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Delete/after a month");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
      {
        threads[i].moveToTrash();
      }
  }
}

I should make this a subroutine... and three new scripts to call it, with different values of delaydays and label name.

Comment: Bounded scripts are scripts attached to docs, sheets or  forms. Usually only accesible through the sheet or doc or form. Glad it helped